# Proving that any odd integer divided by $2$ ends in $0.5$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that any **Odd** integer *N* divided by 2 ends in 0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, an odd number is n+1 where n is even, so we have :
$$\frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{n}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}\:\:and\:\: \frac{1}{2} = 0.5$$

Answer (score 3):

The definition of an odd integer is when it's divided by 2, it has a remainder of 1. Therefore, it can be written as

$$n=2k+1$$ where k is an integer.

When divided by 2, $$\frac{n}{2}=k+\frac{1}{2}=k+0.5$$

Since k is an integer, the quotient ends with 0.5

Answer (score 2):

A number $n$ can be equivalent to $0$ or $1$ in $\mod 2$. When $n$ is even, we can write $n$ as:
$$n=2k+1, k\in N$$
So, diving by $2$ we obtain:
$$T=\frac{n}{2}=\frac{2k+1}{2}=k+\frac{1}{2}$$
Being $k \in N$, when have that $\{T\}=0.5$.